# Segmentation fault (core dumped) ! structs, arrays

Tags: arrays, struct

getting an error in my 'for loop'.

the program compiles and executes,

but when i try to use code from case NEW_GAME: in my switch statement, the program 'hangs' then outputs **'Segmentation fault (core dumped)'** which i think means the program is trying to access some chunk of memory but i don't understand why this is occurring ...

...since i tried filling,  **new_map.items[index].type** manually at each index and it worked fine!

everytime i comment out the loop the program will run the way i want. so i believe its the loop.

**SOURCE CODE:**

struct MapItem {

```
char type = 'E';
```

};

struct Map {

```
int size;
MapItem *items;
```

};

int main () {

```
int selection;
int map_size;
Map new_map;
MapItem new_map_item;


enum MenuOptions {
 INIT = -1,
 NEW_GAME =1,
 PRINT_MAP,
 BUILD,
 EXIT_PROGRAM
};

while (selection != EXIT_PROGRAM) {

  cout << endl;
  cout << NEW_GAME<< ". New Game" << endl;
  cout << PRINT_MAP << ". Print Map" << endl;
  cout << BUILD << ". Build Something" << endl;
  cout << EXIT_PROGRAM << ". Exit" << endl;

  //get selection , cin >> int , return int,
  selection = get_selection();
  
  switch (selection) {
      
 case NEW_GAME:

//int map size (just extra variable i wanted to add)
//create_new_game () returns int , gets size for map.
// map is a one dimensional array of chars. map size will be a
// square (size*size) 

        map_size = create_new_game();
        new_map.size = (map_size*map_size);
        new_map.items = &new_map_item;
        
        // test statements, code works if for loop is not there
        cout << new_map.size;
        cout << new_map.items[0].type;
    
        //
        //   ! WHERE ERROR OCCURS !
        //

        for ( int index = 0; index <= (new_map.size); index++ ) {
            new_map.items[index].type = new_map_item.type;
        }
        
         break;
```

```
    **COMMAND LINE INPUT/OUTPUT:**
    
    $ make
    g++ -std=c++11 -c -Wall main.cpp
    g++ -std=c++11 main.o -o driver
    
    
    $ ./driver.exe
    
    1. New Game
    2. Print Map
    3. Build Something
    4. Exit
    Enter your selection: 1

What size map would you like? 3
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Answer (score 1):

`for ( int index = 0; index <= (new_map.size); index++ ) {`

Is going to run you past the end of the map - index run 0 to n-1, you are using 0 to n.

It should be

`for ( int index = 0; index < (new_map.size); index++ ) {`

Comment: i actually just figured that out and also how to stop the run time error
it seems to work when i use (index < map_size) 

where map_size is an int that has the updated size.

Answer (score -1):

i have fixed the runtime error, which fixed by, changing the condition in the loop

```
for ( int index = 0; index < map_size; index++ ) {
                new_map.items[index].type = new_map_item.type;
                cout << index;
}
```

where map_size is an int with the updated value, still not sure how this makes sense but it works.

Comment: It's exactly what I said in my answer - you are going 0 to size-1 (correct) instead of the original 0 to size (one too many). You originally had `<=` when you should have had `<`)

Comment: well not exactly, i tried switching the operators and it still didn't work until i switched out the right hand side of the comparison to an int.